# Unable to run an Eclipse project in a local web browser, access the database, and run the project

Tags: java, database, myeclipse, jdbc-odbc

I am currently doing a web application project in Eclipse. I understand that the project done in eclipse runs on a local web browser (i.e. in my eclipse web browser). What I don't understand, if how we can execute or run that project in my local browser, such as Google Chrome, or Firefox etc.,

In order to do this, I tried to copy the web url address from eclipse and pasting it into Chrome. The user interface is working fine. That said, it was not supporting the database when i tried to login. Logging in gave me the message "login failed".

Can some please help explain where to store my database and how to run my project in a web browser that is built in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference accessing the application from the MyEclipse web browser or from an external web browser. The web application is simply serving pages to the browser in response to input from the user. If you are using the built-in Derby database, for testing, make sure the Derby database server is started in MyEclipse (right-click on MyEclipse Derby in the Servers view and select Run Server), before starting the server containing the web application.